# Idaho's southern border looks curved in ArcMap. How do I make Idaho look flat?

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system

I have a polygon of Idaho's borders in ArcMap. The southern border of the state is slightly curved. I realize that the Earth is curved in reality, but I want Idaho to look flat.

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap? I feel like a change in projection or coordinate system might help, but I don't know what those actually do, nor how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Idaho's southern border lies along a so-called "line" of latitude.  (Such "lines" are actually spherical circles centered at the poles.)  *Any* cylindrical projection will render lines of latitude as straight segments on the map.

Comment: Just to clarify Kevin's point, if someone answers your question click the check mark under that answer's vote total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attached image shows four coordinate systems.  The top two are projected coordinate systems and the bottom two are geographic coordinate systems.  I suspect you will like the visual appeal of the Idaho state system located in the top right dataframe.  You can easily experiment with the look of various projections by assigning a projection to the dataframe using the following process:

1. Right click the dataframe in the table of contents, select
   Properties > Coordinate System
2. In the Coordinate System tab, choose any of the many projected or
   geographic coordinate systems
3. To find the Idaho state system, select Projected Coordinate Systems > State Systems > NAD 1983 Idaho TM (Meters)

Keep in mind these changes are temporary and only apply to the dataframe properties.  If you would like to make the projection permanent, use the [Project (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000) tool

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that when GIS software displays data in a "geographic" coordinate system", *it is still projected* in order to be displayed on your two-dimensional screen. It uses the [equirectangular projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection), which has degrees of longitude as the x and y axes.